# Anthology that retold well known stories from other viewpoints or with twisted endings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I have been trying to find this book for years. I bought it when I was 16/17 (2001 or so) so I *assume* it was published in the 90's or early 00's.

The book had a purple cover. It was an anthology that retold well known stories from other viewpoints or with twisted endings.

The only 2 story plots I somewhat remember are:

1. Snow White; told from one of the dwarfs point of view. Snow White dies and the dwarfs then traveled to seek revenge for her death.
2. Hamlet, told from Ophelia's point of view (they never actually mention the name Hamlet but if you're familiar with the play you know exactly what it is). It ends with her committing suicide.

Googling has led me nowhere. I've posted on other forums before finding this one. Hoping someone has any idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE mergedloki! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the book that you are searching for.

Comment: There is a book https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/293583.Ophelia which sounds similar to your 2nd plot. But that was published 2006.

Comment: Were any of them science fiction or fantasy? (not sure retellings of fairy tales count as the latter but who knows)

Comment: @AakahM Fairy tales do count: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3414/60757

Comment: Ophelia commits suicide in the original play. How is there a twist?

Comment: @Valorum I'm going off a 16 year old memory here. Haven't read Hamlet in 16+ years didn't remember. And the story was told from Ophelia's POV which would be the 'twist' I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't it, but the first one sounds similar to a Neil Gaiman short story, "Snow, Glass and Apples", from the book Smoke and Mirrors.

The UK version of the book is purple: 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Smoke-Mirrors-Neil-Gaiman/dp/0755322835

[image: Book]

That aside, I'm not sure if I recognize the second story mentioned - a lot of his short stories are based off of works of fiction that I ought to recognize, yet don't, so might be worth a shot.

Comment: How does the first story match?

Comment: I might be mixing the memories of that story with another of his involving snow white and sleeping beauty, and also dwarves. Dwarves are mentioned in both, though in the first story they do not sound kind or at all friendly

Comment: I have the book Smoke and Mirrors and I can't see any similarity between *Snow, Glass and Apples* and the story the OP describes. In *Snow, Glass and Apples* dwarves are hardly mentioned, and Snow White doesn't die (she has her heart cut out but lives on as a sort of lich like creature).